# Simple flask server running on windows machine and static IP invisible outside

Tags: python, flask, windows-10

I just ran this simple python code to start a server on my windows 10 Pro laptop. In case it's important, I'm doing it from Jupyter Notebook

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

If I go to `localhost:5000` on my browser, I see `'Hello World'`. Note that I am assigned a static IP address. If I now go to XX.XXX.XX.XXX:5000 (XX.XXX.XX.XXX is my static IP) from another computer -- my cell phone, I can't find any content. I am not running the code debug mode and I even turned off the firewall, but nothing. Can any of you please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks very much in advance

Comment: did you do the port forwarding? 5000 to 5000.

Comment: how you're running your app?

Comment: When entering your static IP on your computer, is this working ?

Comment: I did not do the forwarding. Can you please send me a link to it? If I enter my IP it sends me to the NBG-418N v2 Embedded WEB Configurator

Comment: The static IP address belongs to your router, not to your computer. The router assigns your computer an internal, local IP address. So, you need to configure port forwarding in your router to forward the incoming traffic to your computer.

Comment: You're right. This was the cause. I was using the address assigned by the browser, not by my internet provider. Unfortunately it is dynamic (I would prefer it to be static)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today and solved it by doing the following:

- You need to get the ip address of your machine. On windows you can get it using the command 'ipconfig' in the cmd.
- Ensure your host = 0.0.0.0 in the flask app (which it does from looking at your code)
- Run the flask server and then open the browser on your mobile. Now enter the IP of your machine followed by the port your server is running from and you should be set. (example: 192.168.x.xx:5000/)